# How can i solve this )

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Please Help. Im following tutorial on youtube (channel: coding in flow). Its about making a todo app in kotlin using android studio, and i got stuck on this:

taskDao.update(task.copy(completed = isChecked))

Error: Unresolved reference copy.

Tryed a lot of things but didnt help.

Comment: If possible, please provide more code and context. What kind of class is `task` an instance of?

Answer (score 1):

`task` is most likely an instance of a `data class` which has its own `copy()` method. If you have access to this class, make sure it is a `data class` and not a `class`.